# How to temporarily disable UIView background image from responding to mouse clicks in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a UIView background image that I want to use for my view.

Now, on top of this image, I want to have buttons and position them relative to what I see in the image.

The problem is, these buttons were already added to the view before the background image was added. So now when I put the background image, entire view is background image and I am unable to access the buttons underneath it in Xcode.

Is there a way to tell Xcode that I am not interested in the UIView but actually the buttons that appear underneath it?

Answer (score 0):

Check `- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view` in [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Would be something like

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView];
```